# VB.NET Application timeout on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am getting a SQL Timeout issue with a VB.NET application even though I have set the Query timeout to 0 (Never) in SQL Server 2012.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I am inserting a lot of records.

Comment: Whats your code look like? Are you getting any specific exceptions?

Comment: It's quite possible your `SqlConnection` is timing out, even though you've set it on the server for never.  If you're inserting a lot of records, you might want to look at batch processing.

Comment: OK - I might have to split the files into smaller files, I haven't got access to the code but I am sure it does not specify a timeout. I thought it would take the default server timeout in that case?

Comment: @techguy1988 - Actually, the setting in the client would be the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` - `SqlConnection.Timeout` is simply for connecting to the server, it has nothing to do with the exeuction of the the command.  The default is 30 seconds.

Comment: Ok I cant change the VB.NET app it's already build and compiled. It comes back with an error saying "Query timeout" is there anyway (outside the program) to up the query timeout?

Comment: Most likely not.  You could ask the program developer to change it or make it configurable, but that's about all I can think of.